# "in a brisk pace" vs "with a brisk pace" vs "at a brisk pace"

Tags: grammar

He walked at a brisk pace. This is the standard usage, I get it.
If I want to describe the pacing of a story, can I say he wrote his lifestory with a brisk pace?
Also, is in a brisk pace acceptable?

Comment: Make sure you describe the pacing of the story, and not how quickly the author wrote the story.  Using subject "He wrote" as the subject may seem to be the latter.    Maybe try "The story has a brisk pace" or something.

Comment: You need a clear what it is for a life story to be ‘brisk’.  Verse can obviously be brisk (lots of short syllables, metre such as anapaest, as in limerick).  But prose is a bit more subtle.

Answer (score 1):

In making our choice it is important that the preposition describes the relation we intend and the word/phrase to which it is applied.

'Brisk pace' is a specific speed, and so falls neatly in the 'at speed', 'at a slow rate' etc.

'With' implies we are taking it along with us, and we could indeed say 'we move with speed', so it is arguable to use 'with a brisk pace', such as in 'with a pen and brisk pace'. On its own, though, we might start asking why not use 'at' instead, or, worse, our readers might start asking.

'In' sounds like many translations, where the translator attempts to bring a specific construction that works well in the source language into English, with the hope that it will still work here.

Answer (score 1):

> Can I say he wrote his lifestory with a **brisk pace**?

In

*Teller of Tales: The Life of Arthur Conan Doyle*  [google books](https://books.google.com/books?id=3BR8AgAAQBAJ&lpg=PA120&dq=he%20wrote%20his%20story%20at%20a%20brisk%20pace&pg=PA120#v=onepage&q=he%20wrote%20his%20story%20at%20a%20brisk%20pace&f=false), a sentence appears to provide grammar similar to your question:

> The short story format offered a compact execution and brisk pace, and
>   highlighted Conan Doyle's singular talent for puzzling plots.

*Your use of **brisk pace** is grammatical.*  From a book review:

> Once again, this story showcases fine writing at a brisk pace with no
>   dallying. I don't mind that it's a novella, shorter than the average
>   novel.

Thus the following suggestion:

> His life story was a page-turner, written at (or with) a brisk pace

is proposed.

Comment: written at a brisk pace? How could a reviewer know what pace the author used in writing??

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the comments that stress that one must make sure that *a brisk pace* describes the pace of the story itself rather than of the writing of the story.

For example, to my ear, the book review mentioned in [lbf's answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/469121/155553)

[1] *this story showcases fine writing at a brisk pace with no dallying*

uses a construction that is better suited to describe the pace of the writing. It is only with some effort that one yields to the pressure of context and reinterprets it as describing the pace of the story itself. Furthermore, to my ear at least, lbf's suggested construction

[2] *his life story was a page-turner, written at* (or *with*) *a brisk pace*

suggests even more strongly than [1] does that we are talking about the actual writing, to the point of actually being ambiguous: as a reader, I would be unsure whether the writer meant the pace of the story, which would make sense given the context (*a page-turner*), or the pace of the actual writing.

On the other hand, the construction in *Teller of Tales: The Life of Arthur Conan Doyle*,

[3] *the short story format offered a compact execution and brisk pace*

is naturally **and efortlessly** read as describing the pace of the story.

## **My propoal**

Having studied the various constructions in which *a brisk pace* appears in published literature (see below), I think something like the following could work for you:

> He wrote his life story so that it [had]/[maintained]/[kept up]/[sustained]/[featured]/[marked]/[kept on] a brisk pace.
>
> He wrote his life story so that it [moves/flows] [at/with/in] a brisk pace.
>
> He wrote his life story so that it is characterized by a brisk pace.
>
> The writing keeps his life story on a brisk pace.

## ***A brisk pace* in published literature**

It may be worth listing some of the constructions in which *brisk pace* appears in published literature, other than *at a brisk pace*. Other than in that construction, it does not appear as a complement in a preposition phrase that often. Examples of when it does include [*to*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&hl=en&q=%22to+a+brisk+pace%22) (note also the relevant verbs)

*He **slowed to a brisk pace.*** 
*His game just naturally **lent** itself **to a brisk pace.*** 
*Stifflegged, hestood up, **forced** himself **to a brisk pace.*** 
*I hurried out of the town, and **putting** my horse **to a brisk pace** made the best of my way across the plain.*
*Group warm-up stroll, **progressing** gently **to a brisk pace.***

*with*

*After a few blocks, she found it difficult to keep walking **with a brisk pace.*** [(source)](https://books.google.com/books?id=xd4bbY03Yl0C&lpg=PA13&dq=%22with%20a%20brisk%20pace%22&pg=PA13#v=onepage&q=%22with%20a%20brisk%20pace%22&f=false)
*We'll get some rhythm started here and see what happens.” Al and Bobby responded

     **with a brisk pace,** but Nina wanted more.* [(source)](https://books.google.com/books?id=jRoy0ZDBRwAC&lpg=PA98&dq=%22with%20a%20brisk%20pace%22&pg=PA98#v=onepage&q=%22with%20a%20brisk%20pace%22&f=false)
***With a brisk pace,** she crossed the aisle.* [(source)](https://books.google.com/books?id=O6awBAAAQBAJ&lpg=PA4&dq=%22with%20a%20brisk%20pace%22&pg=PA4#v=onepage&q=%22with%20a%20brisk%20pace%22&f=false)

and, much more rarely,

*in*:

*Wheeler approached the boat ramp **in a brisk pace** growing angrier as he got closer.* [(source)](https://books.google.com/books?id=dVGPAAAAQBAJ&lpg=PA251&dq=%22in%20a%20brisk%20pace%22&pg=PA251#v=onepage&q=%22in%20a%20brisk%20pace%22&f=false)
*She left the house **in a brisk pace.*** [(source)](https://books.google.com/books?id=BYuOAAAAQBAJ&lpg=PA30&dq=%22She%20left%20the%20house%20in%20a%20brisk%20pace.%22&pg=PA30#v=onepage&q=%22She%20left%20the%20house%20in%20a%20brisk%20pace.%22&f=false)

There is also a version without the article, though this could be a typo:

*Frederick took long strides **in brisk pace** across sheets of ice.* [(source)](https://books.google.com/books?id=4e3xAgAAQBAJ&lpg=PT59&dq=%22in%20brisk%20pace%22&pg=PT59#v=onepage&q=%22in%20brisk%20pace%22&f=false)

*into*:

*Peewee moved **into a brisk pace** and kept stepping it up.* [(source)](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&hl=en&q=%22into+a+brisk+pace%22)

*from*:

*…academic pressure resulting **from a brisk pace**…* [(source)](https://books.google.com/books?id=41p6_H7DSvMC&lpg=PA54&dq=%22from%20a%20brisk%20pace%22&pg=PA54#v=onepage&q=%22from%20a%20brisk%20pace%22&f=false)

*of*:

*September's preliminary 9.9% year-to- year advance by unit sales of US-built light motor vehicles upholds the continuation **of a brisk pace** of US household expenditures.*  [(source)](https://books.google.com/books?id=KNobAQAAMAAJ&q=%22of+a+brisk+pace%22&dq=%22of+a+brisk+pace%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj3qarN25LeAhVSt1MKHTnHBpoQ6AEILzAB)

*by*

*Perhaps the most useful technique is careful planning with marking of surgical margins, followed **by a brisk pace** of excision and immediate application of hemostatic wraps.* [(source)](https://books.google.com/books?id=pSJLBAAAQBAJ&lpg=PA760&dq=%22by%20a%20brisk%20pace%22&pg=PA760#v=onepage&q=%22by%20a%20brisk%20pace%22&f=false)

***On a brisk pace*** seems to have been common in the early 1800s. Today it's rare, but there is an attested example here, which to me sounds quite natural:

*Viets's energetic storytelling keeps* Fixing to Die ***on a brisk pace.*** [(source)](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&hl=en&q=%22on+a+brisk+pace%22)

Much more commonly, *a brisk pace* appears as the object of transitive verbs, especially the following ones:

*She **kept** a brisk pace as she tried to make the lights at each corner.* [(source)](https://www.google.com/search?num=100&hl=en&tbm=bks&ei=sePJW40nxrfPAuKxqfAJ&q=%22kept+a+brisk+pace%22&oq=%22kept+a+brisk+pace%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3...36588.37329.0.38346.4.4.0.0.0.0.96.367.4.4.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.0.0....0.OqMx4Up8qJU)
*I **kept up** a brisk pace.* [(source)](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&hl=en&q=%22kept+up+a+brisk+pace%22)
*They were very enthusiastic and were **setting** a brisk pace.* [(source)](https://books.google.com/books?id=0mV9nHPi6kwC&lpg=PA106&dq=%22a%20brisk%20pace%22%20-%22at%20a%20brisk%20pace%22%20%20-%22set%20a%20brisk%20pace%22%20-%22keep%20a%20brisk%20pace%22%20-%22keeping%20a%20brisk%20pace%22%20-%22kept%20a%20brisk%20pace%22%20-%22at%20such%20a%20brisk%20pace%22%20-%22maintain%20a%20brisk%20pace%22%20-%22maintained%20a%20brisk%20pace%22%20-%22maintaining%20a%20brisk%20pace%22&pg=PA106#v=onepage&q=%22setting%20a%20brisk%20pace%22&f=false)
*Wheeling, she **adopts** a brisk pace, then forces herself to slow down.* [(source)](https://books.google.com/books?id=ZNgrSR2uV60C&lpg=PA34&dq=%22adopts%20a%20brisk%20pace%22&pg=PA34#v=onepage&q=%22adopts%20a%20brisk%20pace%22&f=false)
*He and the old man **struck** a brisk pace down the trail.* [(source)](https://www.google.com/search?num=100&hl=en&tbm=bks&ei=rN7JW7DJCISkzwKGobDACg&q=%22struck+a+brisk+pace%22&oq=%22struck+a+brisk+pace%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3...5638.7489.0.8074.6.6.0.0.0.0.101.532.5j1.6.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.0.0....0.dhNSyo8Sfbk)
*The birds chirped wildly as she turned and **walked** a brisk pace deeper into the woods.* [(source)](https://books.google.com/books?id=0IdquVtfbiAC&lpg=PT19&dq=%22a%20brisk%20pace%22%20-%22at%20a%20brisk%20pace%22%20%20-%22set%20a%20brisk%20pace%22%20-%22keep%20a%20brisk%20pace%22%20-%22keeping%20a%20brisk%20pace%22%20-%22kept%20a%20brisk%20pace%22%20-%22at%20such%20a%20brisk%20pace%22%20-%22maintain%20a%20brisk%20pace%22%20-%22maintained%20a%20brisk%20pace%22%20-%22maintaining%20a%20brisk%20pace%22&pg=PT20#v=onepage&q=%22a%20brisk%20pace%22&f=false)
*For the next hundred yards or so, they **maintained** a brisk pace.* [(source)](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&hl=en&q=%22maintained+a+brisk+pace%22)
*Judge followed Storey at a close distance, the two **marking** a brisk pace.* [(source)](https://books.google.com/books?id=b1pqo-bQJbMC&lpg=PA494&dq=%22marking%20a%20brisk%20pace%22&pg=PA494#v=onepage&q=%22marking%20a%20brisk%20pace%22&f=false)
*Keys in hand, car locked in her wake, she **picked up** a brisk pace for his door.* [(source)](https://books.google.com/books?id=S1qfBgAAQBAJ&lpg=PT79&dq=%22a%20brisk%20pace%22%20-%22at%20a%20brisk%20pace%22%20%20-%22set%20a%20brisk%20pace%22%20-%22keep%20a%20brisk%20pace%22%20-%22keeping%20a%20brisk%20pace%22%20-%22kept%20a%20brisk%20pace%22%20-%22at%20such%20a%20brisk%20pace%22%20-%22maintain%20a%20brisk%20pace%22%20-%22maintained%20a%20brisk%20pace%22%20-%22maintaining%20a%20brisk%20pace%22&pg=PT79#v=onepage&q=%22a%20brisk%20pace%22&f=false)
*The hour **had** a brisk pace despite Como's casualness and got exceptional mileage out of the set.* [(source)](https://books.google.com/books?id=V2orAwAAQBAJ&lpg=PA138&dq=%22a%20brisk%20pace%22%20-%22at%20a%20brisk%20pace%22%20%20-%22set%20a%20brisk%20pace%22%20-%22keep%20a%20brisk%20pace%22%20-%22keeping%20a%20brisk%20pace%22%20-%22kept%20a%20brisk%20pace%22%20-%22at%20such%20a%20brisk%20pace%22%20-%22maintain%20a%20brisk%20pace%22%20-%22maintained%20a%20brisk%20pace%22%20-%22maintaining%20a%20brisk%20pace%22&pg=PA138#v=onepage&q=%22a%20brisk%20pace%22&f=false)
*They **took** a brisk pace through the forest.* [(source)](https://books.google.com/books?id=39KZAwAAQBAJ&lpg=PA61&dq=%22a%20brisk%20pace%22%20-%22at%20a%20brisk%20pace%22%20%20-%22set%20a%20brisk%20pace%22%20-%22keep%20a%20brisk%20pace%22%20-%22keeping%20a%20brisk%20pace%22%20-%22kept%20a%20brisk%20pace%22%20-%22at%20such%20a%20brisk%20pace%22%20-%22maintain%20a%20brisk%20pace%22%20-%22maintained%20a%20brisk%20pace%22%20-%22maintaining%20a%20brisk%20pace%22&pg=PA62#v=onepage&q=%22a%20brisk%20pace%22&f=false)
*Brisbane's 40-page essay (1964, revised 1976) **combines** a brisk pace with attention to detail.* [(source)](https://books.google.com/books?id=Ww5ddqXGPVYC&lpg=PT650&dq=%22a%20brisk%20pace%22%20-%22at%20a%20brisk%20pace%22%20%20-%22set%20a%20brisk%20pace%22%20-%22keep%20a%20brisk%20pace%22%20-%22keeping%20a%20brisk%20pace%22%20-%22kept%20a%20brisk%20pace%22%20-%22at%20such%20a%20brisk%20pace%22%20-%22maintain%20a%20brisk%20pace%22%20-%22maintained%20a%20brisk%20pace%22%20-%22maintaining%20a%20brisk%20pace%22&pg=PT650#v=onepage&q=%22a%20brisk%20pace%22&f=false)
*If they **sustained** a brisk pace, Raszer estimated they'd make their destination…* [(source)](https://books.google.com/books?id=ihexAv0PSs0C&lpg=PA364&dq=%22a%20brisk%20pace%22%20-%22at%20a%20brisk%20pace%22%20%20-%22set%20a%20brisk%20pace%22%20-%22keep%20a%20brisk%20pace%22%20-%22keeping%20a%20brisk%20pace%22%20-%22kept%20a%20brisk%20pace%22%20-%22at%20such%20a%20brisk%20pace%22%20-%22maintain%20a%20brisk%20pace%22%20-%22maintained%20a%20brisk%20pace%22%20-%22maintaining%20a%20brisk%20pace%22&pg=PA364#v=onepage&q=%22a%20brisk%20pace%22&f=false)
*Meanwhile, the dialogue **features** witty repartee and a brisk pace.* [(source)](https://books.google.com/books?id=7OJjS1BlqZ4C&lpg=PT289&dq=%22a%20brisk%20pace%22%20-%22at%20a%20brisk%20pace%22%20%20-%22set%20a%20brisk%20pace%22%20-%22keep%20a%20brisk%20pace%22%20-%22keeping%20a%20brisk%20pace%22%20-%22kept%20a%20brisk%20pace%22%20-%22at%20such%20a%20brisk%20pace%22%20-%22maintain%20a%20brisk%20pace%22%20-%22maintained%20a%20brisk%20pace%22%20-%22maintaining%20a%20brisk%20pace%22&pg=PT289#v=onepage&q=%22a%20brisk%20pace%22&f=false)
*And so he **led** a brisk pace into the grand building.* [(source)](https://books.google.com/books?id=T1rOBAAAQBAJ&lpg=PT536&dq=%22a%20brisk%20pace%22%20-%22at%20a%20brisk%20pace%22%20%20-%22set%20a%20brisk%20pace%22%20-%22keep%20a%20brisk%20pace%22%20-%22keeping%20a%20brisk%20pace%22%20-%22kept%20a%20brisk%20pace%22%20-%22at%20such%20a%20brisk%20pace%22%20-%22maintain%20a%20brisk%20pace%22%20-%22maintained%20a%20brisk%20pace%22%20-%22maintaining%20a%20brisk%20pace%22&pg=PT536#v=onepage&q=%22a%20brisk%20pace%22&f=false)
*Lange's journal holds the record of the trip, and it **describes** a brisk pace.* [(source)](https://books.google.com/books?id=SITY6VZm0hwC&lpg=PA1&dq=%22a%20brisk%20pace%22%20-%22at%20a%20brisk%20pace%22%20%20-%22set%20a%20brisk%20pace%22%20-%22keep%20a%20brisk%20pace%22%20-%22keeping%20a%20brisk%20pace%22%20-%22kept%20a%20brisk%20pace%22%20-%22at%20such%20a%20brisk%20pace%22%20-%22maintain%20a%20brisk%20pace%22%20-%22maintained%20a%20brisk%20pace%22%20-%22maintaining%20a%20brisk%20pace%22&pg=PA1#v=onepage&q=%22a%20brisk%20pace%22&f=false)
*The afternoon had been crisp, **necessitating** a brisk pace to keep warm.* [(source)](https://books.google.com/books?id=3QP7LrdEvNkC&lpg=PA205&dq=%22necessitating%20a%20brisk%20pace%22&pg=PA205#v=onepage&q=%22necessitating%20a%20brisk%20pace%22&f=false)
*His step **measured** a brisk pace.* [(source)](https://books.google.com/books?id=8i_-ltaKB0kC&lpg=PA419&dq=%22His%20step%20measured%20a%20brisk%20pace%22&pg=PA419#v=onepage&q=%22His%20step%20measured%20a%20brisk%20pace%22&f=false)
*Fortunately Appleby did now seem to be **proposing** a brisk pace.* [(source)](https://books.google.com/books?id=q5KXDQAAQBAJ&lpg=PT133&dq=%22Fortunately%20Appleby%20did%20now%20seem%20to%20be%20proposing%20a%20brisk%20pace.%22&pg=PT133#v=onepage&q=%22Fortunately%20Appleby%20did%20now%20seem%20to%20be%20proposing%20a%20brisk%20pace.%22&f=false)
*This hike **requires** a brisk pace to complete before the last ferry.*  [(source)](https://books.google.com/books?id=a2xBBAAAQBAJ&lpg=PA283&dq=%22This%20hike%20requires%20a%20brisk%20pace%20to%20complete%20before%20the%20last%20ferry.%20%22&pg=PA284#v=onepage&q=%22This%20hike%20requires%20a%20brisk%20pace%20to%20complete%20before%20the%20last%20ferry.%20%22&f=false)
*You'll need an early start and **a brisk pace** to get to the first village south of the divide before nightfall on the second day.* [(source)](https://books.google.com/books?id=KLUJWJU29xAC&lpg=PA135&dq=%22a%20brisk%20pace%22%20-%22at%20a%20brisk%20pace%22%20%20-%22set%20a%20brisk%20pace%22%20-%22keep%20a%20brisk%20pace%22%20-%22keeping%20a%20brisk%20pace%22%20-%22kept%20a%20brisk%20pace%22%20-%22at%20such%20a%20brisk%20pace%22%20-%22maintain%20a%20brisk%20pace%22%20-%22maintained%20a%20brisk%20pace%22%20-%22maintaining%20a%20brisk%20pace%22&pg=PA135#v=onepage&q=%22a%20brisk%20pace%22&f=false)
*These publications **reflect** a brisk pace of expansion of the probabilistic methodology in solving environmental problems.* [(source)](https://books.google.com/books?id=eXSjAQAAQBAJ&lpg=PA6&dq=%22These%20publications%20reflect%20a%20brisk%20pace%20of%20expansion%20of%20the%20probabilistic%20methodology%20in%20solving%20environmental%20problems.%22&pg=PA6#v=onepage&q=%22These%20publications%20reflect%20a%20brisk%20pace%20of%20expansion%20of%20the%20probabilistic%20methodology%20in%20solving%20environmental%20problems.%22&f=false)
*An acceleration of household Income growth and near euphoric levels of consumer confidence should **sustain** a brisk pace of home sales.* [(source)](https://books.google.com/books?id=U9sbAQAAMAAJ&q=%22An+acceleration+of+household+Income+growth+and+near+euphoric+levels+of+consumer+confidence+should+sustain+a+brisk+pace+of+home+sales%22&dq=%22An+acceleration+of+household+Income+growth+and+near+euphoric+levels+of+consumer+confidence+should+sustain+a+brisk+pace+of+home+sales%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjw55v04JLeAhWS3lMKHd8TBJ8Q6AEIKTAA)

Also frequent are constructions where *a brisk pace* is the subject:

*Too slow a pace gives your dog time to sniff, look around, and in general become distracted; **a brisk pace** focuses the dog's attention upon you and generally aids training.* [(source)](https://books.google.com/books?id=jNMs4xPckVwC&lpg=PA112&dq=%22a%20brisk%20pace%22%20-%22at%20a%20brisk%20pace%22%20%20-%22set%20a%20brisk%20pace%22%20-%22keep%20a%20brisk%20pace%22%20-%22keeping%20a%20brisk%20pace%22%20-%22kept%20a%20brisk%20pace%22%20-%22at%20such%20a%20brisk%20pace%22%20-%22maintain%20a%20brisk%20pace%22%20-%22maintained%20a%20brisk%20pace%22%20-%22maintaining%20a%20brisk%20pace%22&pg=PA112#v=onepage&q=%22a%20brisk%20pace%22&f=false)

We can also have *a brisk pace* appear as a predicative complement:

*If you walk a mile in 20 minutes you're no slouch for it's still **a brisk pace.*** [(source)](https://books.google.com/books?id=iWxsFsHo7xIC&lpg=PA97&dq=%22a%20brisk%20pace%22%20-%22at%20a%20brisk%20pace%22%20%20-%22set%20a%20brisk%20pace%22%20-%22keep%20a%20brisk%20pace%22%20-%22keeping%20a%20brisk%20pace%22%20-%22kept%20a%20brisk%20pace%22%20-%22at%20such%20a%20brisk%20pace%22%20-%22maintain%20a%20brisk%20pace%22%20-%22maintained%20a%20brisk%20pace%22%20-%22maintaining%20a%20brisk%20pace%22&pg=PA97#v=onepage&q=%22a%20brisk%20pace%22&f=false)

Then there are the following constructions:

*In particular, readers will note the presence of several of the skills discussed in Chapters 3 and 4 related to classroom discipline and management: with-it-ness, **a brisk pace,** and clear transitions between activities, among others.* [(source)](https://books.google.com/books?id=HqMXVyTZ1iEC&lpg=PA106&dq=%22a%20brisk%20pace%22%20-%22at%20a%20brisk%20pace%22%20%20-%22set%20a%20brisk%20pace%22%20-%22keep%20a%20brisk%20pace%22%20-%22keeping%20a%20brisk%20pace%22%20-%22kept%20a%20brisk%20pace%22%20-%22at%20such%20a%20brisk%20pace%22%20-%22maintain%20a%20brisk%20pace%22%20-%22maintained%20a%20brisk%20pace%22%20-%22maintaining%20a%20brisk%20pace%22&pg=PA107#v=onepage&q=%22a%20brisk%20pace%22&f=false)

*Around the corner, footsteps came, **a brisk pace,** workmanlike.* [(source)](https://books.google.com/books?id=jnlCNOJyNQkC&lpg=PA1&dq=%22a%20brisk%20pace%22%20-%22at%20a%20brisk%20pace%22%20%20-%22set%20a%20brisk%20pace%22%20-%22keep%20a%20brisk%20pace%22%20-%22keeping%20a%20brisk%20pace%22%20-%22kept%20a%20brisk%20pace%22%20-%22at%20such%20a%20brisk%20pace%22%20-%22maintain%20a%20brisk%20pace%22%20-%22maintained%20a%20brisk%20pace%22%20-%22maintaining%20a%20brisk%20pace%22&pg=PA1#v=onepage&q=%22a%20brisk%20pace%22&f=false)

*I found myself alternating between **a brisk pace** that would bring me to her presence sooner, and a slow, deliberate walk.* [(source)](https://books.google.com/books?id=cerLdlI2lioC&lpg=PA75&dq=%22I%20found%20myself%20alternating%20between%20a%20brisk%20pace%20that%20would%20bring%20me%20to%20her%20presence%20sooner%2C%20and%20a%20slow%2C%20deliberate%20walk%22&pg=PA75#v=onepage&q=%22I%20found%20myself%20alternating%20between%20a%20brisk%20pace%20that%20would%20bring%20me%20to%20her%20presence%20sooner,%20and%20a%20slow,%20deliberate%20walk%22&f=false)

Comment: You give all those alternatives and therefore do not really answer the question at all.  For me, none of them (in the block quote) make much sense at all.

Comment: @Lambie *He wrote his life story so that it is characterized by a brisk pace.* Is it really so that this makes no sense to you?

Comment: That's right: that sentence in italics as written makes no sense. A person can write at a brisk space (I suppose) and his/her story can be fast paced. A face-paced story can usually be read very fast. It is plot heavy. The essential contradiction here is pointed out in my answer and in the comments under the question. Your answer just posts everything as if everything were OK.

Comment: @Lambie What about this example from google books: *Brisbane's 40-page essay (1964, revised 1976) combines **a brisk pace** with attention to detail.* [(source)](https://books.google.com/books?id=Ww5ddqXGPVYC&lpg=PT650&dq=%22Brisbane's%2040-page%20essay%22&pg=PT650#v=onepage&q=%22Brisbane's%2040-page%20essay%22&f=false)

Comment: Of course,  use of "a or the brisk pace" does not require to,in or with. No kind  of pace does: slow pace, fast pace, dragging pace, etc, etc, etc.

Answer (score -1):

Question: Can I say he wrote his lifestory with a brisk pace?

Yes, you can say whatever you like. That is an important point.

After that comes written style, which is actually the point of your question. Preliminarily, it's a good idea to google these types of questions.

1) "at a brisk pace" About 706,000 results (0.26 seconds) [google], including four major dictionaries on the first page: Longman, Merriam-Webster, Cambridge and Collins.

2) "with a brisk pace" About About 1,480 results (1.90 seconds). No dictionary entries. And frankly, I did not bother to look up: in a brisk pace, as it is really off key.

Now, as pace is usually used to refer to walking or talking (delivering a speech) or an activity (moving about), it sounds quite odd to say "one writes at a brisk pace" as it involves the movement of the body.

So, no, **write a story at a brisk pace** doesn't work** and **with a brisk pace** is not standard. That said, one could use this figuratively but it has to be used carefully so as not to sound like one is running while writing. However, a story may be briskly paced, which means it moves along quickly plot-wise.

Suggestion: He wrote the 150-page book fast; it was finished in a week.

Comment: This question is just a baby question and the type that is really an English editing question. Probably not worthy of being here at all.